# Use Service Worker in Plugin

Tags: assets, plugins, files, scope, headers

I am currently working on a plugin that uses a service worker which gets registered  on the front-end by some javascript code and the problem is that the service worker scope is restricted to `/cpresources/610c42da/` as the Asset Manager only serves the file from there.

Here's the code which I currently use to integrate with the front-end:

```php
Craft::$app->getView()
                   ->hook('cachecraft', function () {
                       // Pass the service worker url to the site
                       Craft::$app->getView()
                                  ->registerScript(
                                      'const CACHECRAFT_SERVICE_WORKER = "' .
                                      Craft::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl('@skayo/cachecraft/assetbundles/cachecraft/dist/js/service-worker.js', true) .
                                      '";',
                                      1,
                                      [],
                                      'cachecraft_service_worker'
                                  );

                       // Register asset bundle
                       Craft::$app->getView()
                                  ->registerAssetBundle(CacheCraftAsset::class);
                   });
```

So what I need is to serve my service worker from the root (`https://example.com/service-worker.js`) of the website.
Is that possible somehow?
Another possible way is to serve the file normally at `https://example.com/cpresources/610c42da/service-worker.js` BUT with a Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP Header.
But I don't know how to do that either...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You'd need to set up a frontend route that redirects from `/sw.js` (or whatever) to the actual URL to your resource.

Comment: @andrew.welch Oh no... I just thought it was working when I got this error:  
`The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.`  
I hate this so much 
So no redirects... Need another solution...

Comment: @andrew.welch Okay so I finally solved it by just serving the file within a controller action. This should be good enough... Asset Manager would be better tho....

Comment: @Skayo would you mind adding your solution as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by just serving the file within a controller action like this:

```php
public function actionCacheCraftServiceWorker () {
    $serviceWorkerFile = Craft::getAlias('@skayo/cachecraft/assetbundles/cachecraft/dist/js/CacheCraftServiceWorker.min.js');

    return Craft::$app->getResponse()->sendFile(
        $serviceWorkerFile,
        'CacheCraftServiceWorker.min.js',
        [
            'mimeType' => 'application/javascript',
            'inline' => true
        ]
    );
}
```

and using this event to register the front-end url:

```php
Event::on(
    UrlManager::class,
    UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
    function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
        Craft::debug(
            'UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES',
            __METHOD__
        );
        $event->rules['cache-craft-service-worker'] = [
            'route' => 'cachecraft/frontend/cache-craft-service-worker',
            'suffix' => '.js'
        ];
    }
);
```

Now I can just access it with `https://example.com/cache-craft-service-worker.js` which works perfectly fine.